How to store field Decimal128 into MongoDB Collection with NestJS and TypeORM?
I tried with this:
@Column("Decimal128")
price: Decimal128;

or
@Column({type: "decimal"})
price: Decimal128;

But I always found the price field as
Double
I use this versions
"typeorm": "0.3.20",
"mongodb": "^5.7.0",
"@nestjs/typeorm": "10.0.2",
"@nestjs/core": "10.4.4",

I would expect to find the price field as Decimal128 on the Collection
